# Calling Express by hand

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In a `node.js/express/socket.io` application, how does one "call" `express` by hand to load/render the home page without saying `app.use(blah)`. In other words, if I wanted to tell express to load `index.html` by hand instead of automatically.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    ...

//app.use magically loads index.html when the browser hits 8080
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/www'))); //index.html is in www
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; //select your port or let it pull from your .env file
//===============PORT=================
http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on: ' + port);
}
```

Where index.html is in `www` ? This doesn't work:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html', { root: __dirname + "/relative_path_of_file" } );
});
```

Nor this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('/home/idf/Documents/js/react-trader/client/www/index.html', {user: req.user});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem that is the cause of this question. I am using `Passport` to authenticate `Express`. I needed to protect the home page (index.html), so I added a route and ensured that the user had to be authenticated to view that page. So I said:

```
app.get('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  ...
}
```

The problem is that if I do this, when the user authenticates, I couldn't figure out how to pass control to Express. I either could authenticate (and prevent accessing the home page) through `Passport` routing, or I could do `Express`. But I couldn't do both.

It turns out the answer is really simple (or at least in my very limited understanding at this point) I got to work by simply rewriting to

```
app.get('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
  return next();
}
```

In essence, the way to break out of `Passport` routes and pass control to Express [or "call it by hand" - hence my question] is to `return next();`

This is not obvious at all, and it took quite a bit of experimentation to get it to work.